# fail to read parquet with pd.read_parquet

Tags: pandas, parquet

I've just updated all my conda environments (pandas 1.4.1) and I'm facing a problem with pandas read_parquet function.

```
parquet_file = r'F:\Python Scripts\my_file.parquet'
file= pd.read_parquet(path = parquet_file)
```

it generate the following error:

```
file= pd.read_parquet(parquet_file)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fastparquet\api.py:135 in _parse_header
    fmd = read_thrift(f, parquet_thrift.FileMetaData)

  File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fastparquet\thrift_structures.py:25 in read_thrift
    obj.read(pin)

  File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fastparquet\parquet_thrift\parquet\ttypes.py:1929 in read
    iprot._fast_decode(self, iprot, [self.__class__, self.thrift_spec])

TypeError: got wrong ttype while reading field


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  Input In [14] in <cell line: 1>
    whole_df42= pd.read_parquet(parquet_file)

  File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parquet.py:493 in read_parquet
    return impl.read(

  File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parquet.py:345 in read
    parquet_file = self.api.ParquetFile(path, **parquet_kwargs)

  File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fastparquet\api.py:100 in __init__
    self._parse_header(fn, verify)

  File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fastparquet\api.py:138 in _parse_header
    self.fn)

AttributeError: 'ParquetFile' object has no attribute 'fn'
```

I've tried with different parquet files and nothing.

I've tried to recreate the parquet, simply with:

```
df.to_parquet(parquet_file)
```

from a DataFrame but another error rose.

```
      Traceback (most recent call last):
      File F:\Python Scripts\My_modules\io\df.py:86 in dataframe_to_parquet
        df.to_parquet(full_path, **kwargs)
    
      File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py:207 in wrapper
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    
      File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:2835 in to_parquet
        return to_parquet(
    
      File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parquet.py:420 in to_parquet
        impl.write(
    
      File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parquet.py:301 in write
        self.api.write(
    
      File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fastparquet\writer.py:938 in write
        write_simple(filename, data, fmd, row_group_offsets,
    
      File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fastparquet\writer.py:802 in write_simple
        rg = make_row_group(f, data[start:end], fmd.schema,
    
      File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fastparquet\writer.py:671 in make_row_group
        chunk = write_column(f, data[column.name], column,
    
      File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fastparquet\writer.py:589 in write_column
        bdata = compress_data(bdata, compression)
    
      File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fastparquet\compression.py:113 in compress_data
        raise RuntimeError("Compression '%s' not available.  Options: %s" %
    
    RuntimeError: Compression 'snappy' not available.  Options: ['BROTLI', 'GZIP', 'UNCOMPRESSED']
```

I've used these lines of code dozens of times, I think it is an issue connected with the new release. Is there someone who has a workaround or that could help me understand what is the problem?

thank you.

Comment: Maybe your version of fastparquet is too old. You can try upgrading it in conda. Alternatively you can install pyarrow if fastparquet doesn't work.

Comment: I updated all the packages. fastparquet version is 0.5.

Comment: There must be something wrong, the latest fastparquet version is 0.8.0 https://pypi.org/project/fastparquet/

Comment: You are right, thank you very much. Now It seems to work!!
I thought that was a deeper problem. Sorry for the stupid question.